# Universal link not working for certain top-level domains (.co.uk) but works for .com in iOS

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I am facing an issue with deep links in my iOS app project when it comes to different top-level domains. Deep links work seamlessly for the .com domain, but it does not wok with country specific domain like .co.uk domain.

Both domains have proper Associated Domains set up in the app's entitlement file.

Could anyone suggest what I might be missing because of which some specific domain is not working?

Comment: Do you configure the AASA file in your server?

Comment: For new domain ".co.uk" you should add it to AASA file in your server, after that you should delete your app and install it again. you can check validity of the AASA file in  https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar In Associated domain I have added "*.domain.co.uk". For all sub-domains for example - "xyz.domain.co.uk" my AASA file is configured  and it works fine if I explicitly add "xyz.domain.co.uk" in my associated domain. But for "domain.co.uk" AASA file has not been configured. Do, I need to configure it as well, as I have to cater large number of sub-domains > the Apple doc limitation of 30.